# CDAP execute crud queries

Tags: bigdata, data-lake, cdap

Can we read a each record in file at source and execute individual mysql crud (ex: update / delete) queries for each record at sink?

Thanks & Regards,

Ajay Babu Maguluri.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it at the source, but there is no way currently to customize the query at the sink. I would recommend doing it with triggers on mysql side